# How to re-save a ModelForm?

Tags: python, django, modelform

I instantiate a `ModelForm` based on some input `data`, and then I generate/fetch some new data based on that input data, and want to refresh my `ModelForm` with the new data and then save it afterwards.
I would rather like to use `ModelForm`s as much as possible and avoid having to interact with the associated `Model` object directly when it comes to saving/validation and other stuff (e.g. white-space trimming).

One solution would be to instantiate another new `ModelForm` based on the new (and the previous) data and feeding the constructor the generated `Model` object via `instance` argument, then `save()` again!

But, is there another better/neater/more optimized way, without having to instantiate two `ModelForm`s?

**[app].models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from .custom_fields import HTTPURLField
from .function_validators import validate_md5


class Snapshot(models.Model):
    url = HTTPURLField(max_length=1999)
    content_hash = models.CharField(max_length=32, default='00000000000000000000000000000000',
                                    validators=[validate_md5])
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**[app].forms.py**:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Snapshot


class SnapshotModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Snapshot
        fields = ('url', 'content_hash')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['content_hash'].required = False
```

**[app].views.py**:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import SnapshotModelForm

def index(request):
    snapshot_form = SnapshotModelForm(
        data={'url': ' http://www.baidu.com/ '})

    try:
        model_instance = snapshot_form.save(commit=False)
        generated_new_content_hash = ' 21111111121111111111111111111111  ' # or calculate it from given data! generated_new_content_hash = newdata(model_instance.url)

        snapshot_form2 = SnapshotModelForm(instance=model_instance,
                                           data={'url': model_instance.url,
                                                 'content_hash': generated_new_content_hash })
        snapshot_form2.save()
        return HttpResponse("Saved")
    except ValueError:
        return HttpResponse("Not Saved")
```

In the code above I hard-coded the value of the new "generated/fetched" data for more readability: `generated_new_content_hash=' 21111111121111111111111111111111  '`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need to resave the form, you can add the value in a `clean_content_hash()` method directly on the form: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation

```
class SnapshotModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean_content_hash(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['content_hash']

        if not data:
            data = generated_new_content_hash()

        return data
```

Comment: Does doing this let u benefit from form validation and white-space trimming, which are triggered when u save modelform

Comment: Yes, the `clean()` method will already do all the normal form validation and then any `clean_<fieldname>()` method would be specific for that field. If that field, or another field needed extra white-space trimming you could manually add it with a `clean_<fieldname>()` method.

Comment: What if I don't wanted to implement white-space-trimming myself and wanted to use `ModelForm`s for that purpose?

Comment: @chakmeshma Trimming whitespace automatically happens for forms.CharFields, and occurs in the `CharField.to_python()` method using `strip()`. This is run at the beginning of form validation, separately and before any custom `clean_<fieldname>()` methods are run. -- So, since `content_hash` is a CharField, it will receive automatic white-space trimming: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/fields/#charfield

Answer (score 0):

Maybe explicitly calling the the `__init__` of the `ModelForm` instance with new data!?

```
def index(request):
    snapshot_form = SnapshotModelForm(
        data={'url': ' https://stackoverflow.com/ '})

    try:
        model_instance = snapshot_form.save(commit=False)

        generated_new_content_hash = ' 01111111121111111111111111111111  '  # or calculate it from given data! generated_new_content_hash = newdata(model_instance.url)

        snapshot_form.__init__(instance=model_instance,
                               data={'url': model_instance.url,
                                     'content_hash': generated_new_content_hash})

        snapshot_form.save()
        return HttpResponse("Saved")
    except ValueError:
        return HttpResponse("Not Saved")
```

I tested it and it works, but I need to know if it's a legit and valid thing to do, and won't cause problems in future?!